# React.js How do I use a component in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use a component in another component like so in react...

```js
var ContentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="box center-block">
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Quotesection = React.createClass({
    render:function () {
        return(
            <ContentBox><h1 className="text-center">Example text</h1></ContentBox>

        );
    }
});



ReactDOM.render(<ContentBox/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

But all I get is the box instead of the box and the Quote inside the box. If anyone can help that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you provided you're not using `Quotesection` at all.

Try this instead:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Quotesection/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, I'm wondering why its done this way though. So if I wanted to add another component I would have to call that newly created component in the ReactDOM.render so its kinda like its a composition. Is the way I am doing it the right way to go about it if I want to use multiple components?

Comment: Yes. Normally you would have a high-level component that's composed of other components. No different than a webpage is normally constructed with pure html.